# How to combine two sql statements or how to fetch data from two tables to login?

Tags: sql, asp.net

For user login we have to fetch username and password from two different tables as for student we are fetching them from `Student_Main_Email` and in case of  Faculty we are fetching them from `Faculty_Revewier_Email` Table so in a stored procedure we union two select quires this logic work for `Student_Main_Table` but not for the other.
Can you please suggest us a better solution that how we can merge these two quires.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SpUserLogin] 
@Email nvarchar(100),
@Password nvarchar(15)
as
Begin 
select count(Email) from Student_Main_Email
where [Email]=@Email and [Password]=@Password

Union All 
select count(Email) from Faculty_Reviewer_Email
where [Email]=@Email and [Password]=@Password
End
```

And ASP.NET Code is

```
protected void Login_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionstring = "Data Source=NADIR\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PHD_System_new;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpUserLogin", con);
        SqlParameter paramusername = new SqlParameter("@Email", Login_Email.Value);
        SqlParameter parampassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", Login_Password.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramusername);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parampassword);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        int returncode = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (returncode == 1)
        {
            Session["LoginUserName"] = Login_Email.Value;

            Server.Transfer("WebForm1.aspx");
            //lblMessage.Text = "User Name or Password is valid.";

        }
        else {
            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid User Name or Password.";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Add your code as a text, not as a image

Answer (score 0):

you can add a helper column to define each row source and the chose according the different cases:

```
select count(Email), 'student' as source from Student_Main_Email
where [Email]=@Email and [Password]=@Password

Union All 
select count(Email), 'faculty' as source from Faculty_Reviewer_Email
where [Email]=@Email and [Password]=@Password
```

Comment: Thanks sir let me try it

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter proc login(     --exec login 'ravi','123',''
@Email varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@Msg varchar(50) output
)
as
begin 
if exists(select * from student_mail_Email  where @Email=Email and @Password=Password)
        begin
        select @Msg='Success'
        end
        else

if exists(select * from Faculty_Revewier_Email where @Email=Email and @Password=Password)
        begin
        select @Msg='Success'
        end
        else

begin
select @Msg='User Does not exists'
end
select @Msg
end
```

[image]